# How to eliminate blanks from SQL Summary Row with Totals with ROLLUP

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, rollup

I have the following SQL in Sql server 2016. I am trying to capture Totals of Site in Column and then Sum total in Row with ROLLUP. However, I am getting Nulls as well. I am providing sample data here:

```
            create table #tempSite
                (
                Report_Date smalldatetime null,
                Code varchar(10) null,
                DepSite varchar(10) null
                )

                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-22', 'ABCDE', 'NC')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-22', 'ABCDE', 'SC')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-22', 'ABCDE', 'FL')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-22', 'ABCDE', 'SC')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-22', 'ABCDE', 'FL')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-22', 'ABCDE', 'NC')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-22', 'ABCDE', 'SC')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-22', 'ABCDE', 'NC')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-22', 'UVXYZ', 'NC')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-22', 'UVXYZ', 'SC')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-22', 'UVXYZ', 'NC')

                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-23', 'ABCDE', 'NC')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-23', 'ABCDE', 'SC')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-23', 'ABCDE', 'FL')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-23', 'ABCDE', 'SC')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-23', 'PQRST', 'FL')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-23', 'ABCDE', 'NC')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-23', 'ABCDE', 'SC')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-23', 'ABCDE', 'NC')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-23', 'UVXYZ', 'NC')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-23', 'PQRST', 'SC')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-23', 'UVXYZ', 'NC')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-23', 'UVXYZ', 'CA')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-23', 'PQRST', 'CA')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-23', 'UVXYZ', 'MD')

                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-24', 'ABCDE', 'NC')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-24', 'ABCDE', 'SC')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-24', 'ABCDE', 'FL')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-24', 'ABCDE', 'SC')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-24', 'PQRST', 'FL')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-24', 'ABCDE', 'NC')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-24', 'ABCDE', 'SC')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-24', 'ABCDE', 'NC')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-24', 'UVXYZ', 'NC')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-24', 'PQRST', 'SC')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-24', 'UVXYZ', 'NC')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-24', 'UVXYZ', 'CA')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-24', 'PQRST', 'CA')
                INSERT INTO #tempSite (Report_Date, Code, DepSite) values ('2020-05-24', 'UVXYZ', 'MD')

                SELECT Report_Date, Code, DepSite, count(DepSite) TOT_SITE
                FROM #tempSite  
                WHERE Code ='ABCDE'in 
                and Report_Date in ('2020-05-22', '2020-05-24')
                group by ROLLUP(Report_Date, Code, DepSite)
```

How can I eliminate NULLS? 
Is there a way to get results like:

```
Report_Date         Code    DepSite TOT_SITE
2020-05-22 00:00:00 ABCDE   FL      2
2020-05-22 00:00:00 ABCDE   NC      3
2020-05-22 00:00:00 ABCDE   SC      3
2020-05-22 00:00:00 NULL    NULL    8
2020-05-24 00:00:00 ABCDE   FL      1
2020-05-24 00:00:00 ABCDE   NC      3
2020-05-24 00:00:00 ABCDE   SC      3
2020-05-24 00:00:00 NULL    NULL    7
NULL                NULL    NULL    15
```

Comment: Edit your results and show the results that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the `GROUP BY` via a `HAVING` clause using the `GROUPING` function:

```
SELECT Report_Date, Code, DepSite, count(DepSite) TOT_SITE
FROM #tempSite  
WHERE Code ='ABCDE'
and Report_Date in ('2020-05-22', '2020-05-24')
group by ROLLUP(Report_Date, Code, DepSite)
having grouping(DepSite) = 0
or grouping (Code) = 1
```

`GROUPING` is 1 when the column is being totalled in that row as part of the `ROLLUP`. So here you check that either the final column (`DepSite`) is not being totalled by the `ROLLUP` (and is thus a standard aggregated row output by the `GROUP BY`) or that `Code` is being totalled and thus that `DepSite` must be too (because you are doing a `ROLLUP` not a `CUBE` and `Code` precedes `DepSite`)

Answer (score 1):

Your result can be achieved using the following query:

```sql
SELECT Report_Date, Code, DepSite, count(DepSite) TOT_SITE
FROM #tempSite  
WHERE Code ='ABCDE' 
and Report_Date in ('2020-05-22', '2020-05-24')
group by ROLLUP(Report_Date, Code, DepSite)
having (Code is not null and DepSite is not null)
  or (Code is null and DepSite is null)
```